# Why does Git pull request contain unmerged branch from previous pull request?

Tags: git, tortoisegit

A couple days ago I cloned the lasted version of a Git repo, made some changes in a file, committed those changes to a new branch `feature\added-support` locally, and then pushed those changes to the Git repo. I then opened a pull request on Bitbucket for those new changes. Now, that pull request is still open because the `feature\added-support` hasn't been merged into the `master` branch.

Today, I cloned a new copy of that repo, switched a particular sub-directory to `feature\added-support`, then made some new changes unrelated to the work done on that branch, committed the new changes to a new branch `feature/changed-debug-msg`, and then pushed those changes to the Git repo. When I opened the pull request in Bitbucket the request for the new branch, now also contains the commit for the `feature\added-support` branch for which there is already a pull request open under the name `Added support for more in depth searching`.

I don't want to have this commit in a new, unrelated pull request. How do I remedy this? I am using Tortoisegit.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you've created both the pull requests against the same branch lets say A in which these you want to merge.

Your first branch is at A+B
Second branch is at A+B+C hence when you created new PR against branch A you're seeing B+C in the diff.

Create PR against first branch you'll see only new changes.

Comment: Makes sense. In Bitbucket, I made the first pull request, for branch B, with the destination of branch A. Now, when I go to make the pull request for branch C, I am making with with the destination of branch A. With this scenario I am still seeing the previous commit of branch B. How do I create the pull request for C just against A as you suggested?

Comment: Create new branch from A and then cherry pick the commit you created on C and create a PR